# Как вывести данные пользователей на отдельных страницах с помощью js?

Tags: firebase

У меня в бд есть данные пользователей, мне нужно вывести данные каждого пользователя на отдельной странице, 1 пользователь - 1 страница с уникальной ссылкой. Как это сделать с помощью js используя единый шаблон на html?